# Warning about fallthrough inside qtestmouse?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, pragma, qttest

I'm using QtTest and just updated to Qt 5.9 and have this kind of warnings:

```
error: use of the 'fallthrough' attribute is a C++1z extension [-Werror,-Wc++1z-extensions]
```

They all point to `Q_FALLTHROUGH()` in `qtestmouse.h`
So obviously I need to add something to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` but can't find out what exactly.

I can ignore these warnings with `pragma` but want to understand this topic a little more.

Comment: What compiler/version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy -- the answer is in the error message, where it says:

> `[-Werror,-Wc++1z-extensions]`

That specifies which warning flags generated this diagnostic.  In our case, we ignore the `-Werror` part as we don't want to turn that whole behavior off, but we can turn the warning off by using the `no-` form of the other flag, namely `-Wno-c++1z-extensions`.

(`Q_FALLTHROUGH()` is expanding to the C++17 `[[fallthrough]]` construct in your case due to the compiler and version you have supporting it.)